# Yii: Creating a Demo Site Without Replicating the Code Base

Tags: php, yii, demo

I need to set up a demo site for users to try a web app before signing up. The demo would be based on production code, however, it would require minor code changes: connection to a demo database, automatic creation/login of a new guest account for each user, etc.

The obvious solution is to replicate my code base as a second demo website and edit as necessary. Keeping the demo code in sync with production code is easy enough by adding a branch in subversion. I'm less than thrilled, however, at the prospect of having to do two updates on my server (production and then demo) every time I push code from development to production.

Initially I thought I might be able to replicate the website through a module. It's unclear if this is possible, however.

Is there a mechanic in Yii to execute an altered version of a website (config file and selected controllers)?

Comment: do you mean multi backends with url like site.com/ and site.com/admin?

Comment: As far as switching between demo/actual database:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/10649-how-to-change-db-name-on-the-fly

Is that not something that could be accomplished with RBAC and/or controller filters and App level parameters?

Comment: Best way to achieve this would be to work with two different config files

Comment: @Stefano Correct. I need the demo site to be accessible from demo.site.com (or equivalently site.com/demo).

Comment: @JPR Unfortunately my use scenarios won't really fit this type of set up well. The users are "curators" who create content that is publicly viewable. To fully demo the system, test users would need to be able to create content (login) and view that content as a guest (logout). I don't really see a simple solution that would hide demo content from the general public, but make it viewable to a demo user. I would prefer to partition all demo content to a separate url.

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge I agree. The implementation details are where I'm a little fuzzy. The solutions provided by Ivan Buttinoni and ernie appear to be promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [testdrive demo app](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app) is configured for this - after you install, note the separate `index-test.php`, and `protected/config/test.php`.

Unlike @IvanButtinoni's suggestion, you'll need to access `index-test.php`, instead of `index.php`, so you may need to modify your .htaccess if you're using clean URLs to allow access to `index-test.php`.

When I do this, I usually write a custom init in the base controller.php:

```
    public function init() {
            // use test layout if using test config
            if (isset(Yii::app()->params['test'])) {
                    $this->layout='//layouts/test';
            }
            parent::init();
    }
```

Obviously, I have a test parameter in my test.php . . .

The only difference in my two layouts is that one sets the background color to be a bright yellow, just so it's very clear you're on a test site.

Comment: This is similar to what I had in mind. From your code snippet it looks like you have a flag in your config file to switch between test and production sites. I need to be able to be able to run both sites simultaneously with site resolution determined by the base url (demo.site.com vs site.com).

Comment: @JasonGeorge I have a test parameter in my test.php config, which is only sourced when you access index-test.php.  It sounds as if you could do the same using URL rewrites.  The main difference between this and Ivan's is that I'm really just documenting how the sample app has done it (the CMap::arrayMerge is in the test config as opposed to how Ivan has it in the index)

Comment: +1 All around. This works exceptionally well. It allows me to set a custom configuration for demo users based on a url. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Never do before, so just an idea

**solution with few files in other dir**

create a separate a demo dir and map it on your demo URL

In this dir put this index.php (may be your .htaccess too)

```
<?php
$yii=_PRODUCTION_PATH_.'/framework/yii.php';
$config_prod=_PRODUCTION_PATH_.'/protected/config/main.php';
$config_demo=dirname(__FILE__).'/demo_main.php';

require_once($yii);

$config = CMap::mergeArray($config_prod,$config_demo);

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

the demo_main.php override the classes (user, db) to manage a better demo experience:

```
<?php
return array(
        'basePath'=>_PRODUCTION_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
        'components'=>array(
             'user' => array(
                  // here you override the user class with a DEMO only user
                  'class'=>'DemoUser',
             )
        ),
```

**solution with all files of prduction site in a different dir**

Here follows the index.php in root dir

```
<?php

$yii='../framework/yii.php';

$configMain = include dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
$configProd = include dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/production.php';
$configDemo = include dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/config/demo.php';

require_once($yii);
// for the demo version
// instead of the comment can be an *if* or any solution to manage 2 configs
//$config = CMap::mergeArray($configMain,$configProd);
$config = CMap::mergeArray($configMain,$configDemo);

Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

**demo.php** is analogue to "demo_main.php" overridig classes and configs for the demo version of the site.

Comment: This looks particularly promising.

Comment: +1 I like the configuration here, but I had some issues with an 'Unable to resolve the request "site".' error and CMap was unavailable prior to require_once($yii). Combining your suggestion for a custom DemoUser class with ernie's configuration should yield a full solution. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonGeorge, I'm bit late, but I fix the CMap issue.
About your question: it seem that you need 2 URL of the "same" site without core duplication and allowing to demo-site to do changes. What about add/modify/deletion of site documents/images?

So I think to a separate dir to avoid files corruption

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well (according to the comment answers to original post) then There are several ways. Here is a link that I think can help great deal. It helped me set up and may be will help you!
In Yii 2 it will be [inherently supported](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36339-frontendbackend-division/page__view__findpost__p__174965)

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/

Comment: +1 Thanks Stefano, this is also helpful. Looking forward to inherent support in Yii 2.